How can I get guest user’s unique visitor ID (UVID)?
There is a method UserInfo.getCurrentUvid() which per documentation is supposed to return guest user’s unique visitor ID (UVID), however, it returns null for us when we try to open public site or Experience Cloud community site in a guest mode.
Why it returns null? How can we get any system unique identifier for a guest user?

related doc - https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/headless-identity-basics/understand-guest-user-identity
